# How to make components responsive?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I build a react step by step form using material UI, I don't understand why I'm getting this behaviour when comes to responsive:

[image: responsive]

It is like eveything goes tiny. How can I properly make it responsive? Thanks!

This is the desktop version:

[image: desktop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to fix that issue on mobile devices.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Put it inside the `<head>` element in your `index.html`.

The attributes supplied in the `content` above is very basic so if you want to add more configurations you can use the other attributes specified below.

> Other attributes that are available are `minimum-scale`, `maximum-scale`,
>   and `user-scalable`. These properties affect the initial scale and
>   width, as well as limiting changes in zoom level.

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) for more information.